# Datatable 1.9.4 edit row with fnUpdate without redraw

Tags: datatable

I would like edita a row without redraw... I use https://legacy.datatables.net/ref#fnUpdate and the function work like this;

```
oTable.fnUpdate( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
```

1. {object|array|string}: Data to update the cell/row with
2. {node|int}: TR element you want to update or the aoData index
3. {int}: The column to update (set to undefined to update the whole row)
4. {bool} [default=true]: Redraw the table or not
5. {bool} [default=true]: Perform pre-draw actions or not

Example:

```
oTable.fnUpdate( 'Example update', 0, 0); // Update Single cell (0,0) and redraw
oTable.fnUpdate( 'Example update', 0, 0, false); // Update Single cell (0,0) and NOT redraw
oTable.fnUpdate( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 1 );    // Update Row 1 and redraw
```

And if i want to update without redraw ???

```
oTable.fnUpdate( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 1, ???, false );    // Update Row 1 and NOT redraw
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find it...

```
oTable.fnUpdate( ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], 1, undefined, false );
```

Answer (score -1):

var rowIndex = $('#example').dataTable().fnGetPosition( element.closest("tr").get(0));
                            $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate( 'Approved', rowIndex , 7,false);

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate( 'Approved', 2, 5,false);//for 3rd row 6 column
 $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate( 'rejected', 2, 6,false);//for 3rd row 7 column
```

or

```
 $('#example').dataTable().fnUpdate( ['Approved',rejected'',...], 2, [0,1,...],false);//for 3rd row all columns
```

Comment: Could you include more explanation in your answer?

Answer (score -1):

Updating the cell content without redrawing the table and without effecting the column width

```js
$('#...').dataTable().fnUpdate(
   'cell data', 
   <row #>,   
   <column #>,
   false,     // redraw as false
   false      // making predraw actions also false
);
```

worked for me